# Join each item of an array by a separator

Tags: javascript, arrays, functional-programming

I am trying to modify each array item and it will join by a separator '-';

Here is the input

```
const bookTitles = [
  'The Culture Code',
  'Designing Your Life',
  'Algorithms to Live By'
];
```

and the expected output:

```
 ['the-culture-code',
 'designing-your-life',
 'algorithms-to-live-by']
```

Comment: Show us what you have tried. SO isn't a free code writing service. The objective here is for you to post your attempts to solve your own issue and others help when they don't work as expected. See [ask] and [mcve]

Answer (score 1):

You can use replaceAll in combination with toLowerCase() to achieve this.

I use map here to build a new array with the updated values.

```js
const bookTitles = [
  'The Culture Code',
  'Designing Your Life',
  'Algorithms to Live By'
];

let modifiedTitles = bookTitles.map((val)=>{
  return val.replaceAll(" ", "-").toLowerCase();
});

console.log(modifiedTitles);
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
const bookTitles = [
  'The Culture Code',
  'Designing Your Life',
  'Algorithms to Live By'
];

const expectedResult = bookTitles.map(item => item.replaceAll(" ", "-").toLowerCase())
console.log(expectedResult)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use map operator or foreach loop and then replace each item space with "-" and convert it to lowercase and return.

```js
const result = [
  'The Culture Code',
  'Designing Your Life',
  'Algorithms to Live By'
].map(v => v.replaceAll(' ', '-').toLowerCase());
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

simply that...

```js
const bookTitles = [
  'The Culture Code',
  'Designing Your Life',
  'Algorithms    to   Live    By'
];

bookTitles.forEach((b,i,t)=>t[i]=b.toLowerCase().replace(/\s+/g,'-'))

console.log( bookTitles )
```